# JAX-RS: Header "Accept-Encoding:gzip/deflate" sufficient for compression

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am using jax-rs and I want to enable compression.

**Is setting the header sufficient to enable compression?**

```
headers.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

According to [How to enable gzip compression for content encoding with Jersey (JAX-RS 2.0) client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519642/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-for-content-encoding-with-jersey-jax-rs-2-0-cli), there is a "GZipEncoder.class" but Jax-RS has not such a class.

```
client.register(GZipEncoder.class);
```

Comment: Is this jersey-client or jersey for the server

Comment: It is the client-side.